# Is there a way, to cast a lambda expression (efficiently) to a function pointer, delegate*<?,?,?,?,>?

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, expression

I currently do this code here:

```
 Fp = (delegate* unmanaged<????bool>)Expression.Lambda(func).Compile().Method.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();
```

But I would like actually to avoid the temporary creation of the Delegate `Expression.Lambda(func).Compile()` and rather go instantly to something like this:

```
Expression.Lambda(func).MakeFuncPointer()
```

That would be cool, so we can instant translate it to that, without the need of creating the temp delegate, which is extra allocation cost.

The `<,,,,>` or `<???>` are placeholders for the exact type matching of the Lambda, you can freely assume they are both of equal signature!

Apparently, I get a runtime-exception: "The requested operation is invalid for DynamicMethod".

Comment: You're compiling an expression, and you're worried about allocating a delegate? Have you measured the memory allocation of the compilation step?

Answer (score 0):

There is a significant difference between function pointers and delegates in that a delegate holds more than just a reference to the function ‒ it can also hold a `this` reference (or the first argument in case of static methods), so you can use it to let the code operate on a captured state (this is called a closed delegate). A function pointer doesn't store any state, so it is simpler, but also limited in certain situations.

This is important because there is no guarantee a particular expression can be compiled in terms of code only. If you use things like `Expression.Constant` for non-primitive values, the object has to be stored alongside the expression, and so the final delegate stores both the compiled method and the closure. Even if you are careful not to create any closure, it is still possible a closed delegate is produced, because not all platforms actually *compile* the expression to code when you call `Compile`. If IL generation is not possible, the expression is *interpreted*, in which case the delegate must be closed to reference the expression itself.

Now on .NET Framework, there is [`LambdaExpression.CompileToMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.compiletomethod?view=netframework-4.8) which can be used to omit the delegate creation and use a `MethodBuilder` instead (but you have to build a whole assembly instead). This is not on .NET Core, due to the aforementioned possibility that the expression has to be interpreted.

All in all, a delegate is in most situations *needed* to make portable code that compiles expressions. Now I have actually [proposed](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/78846) a method that could extract the pointer if possible from the delegate, but if it's closed, there could be other issues (and I think it would be even slower than using the delegate).

If the delegate is open, you may use reflection to obtain the stored pointer, but the internal field is different on different platforms:

```cs
static readonly System.Reflection.FieldInfo methodPtr =
    // .NET
    typeof(Delegate).GetField("_methodPtrAux", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic) ??
    // Mono
    typeof(Delegate).GetField("interp_method", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```